# Link to Joomla article based on URL catching

Tags: html, url, joomla, hyperlink

I am working on a Joomla project.  I need to dynamically link to a unique article based on the event id (not the article url).

The site handles event registration and has multiple events populated based on their event id.

Example here: http://wodrocket.com/index.php?option=com_ohanah&view=event&id=92
Screenshot for clarity:  http://www.diigo.com/item/image/3bgjc/oik2

Need to link to different events result articles.  It should pick up the "id" in the URL and find the results article tied to that event ID.

Articles in joomla don't allow this type of dynamic linking so it will likely need to be a custom url solution.

Comment: do you need to change the number representing the article id in the  URL according the the article ID that you are currently viewing?

Comment: I think what he's after is find further articles that he associates with one. So on the example article he has when he clicks on the see Further results. He wants to find all articles he's associated with the article of id 92